# Issue with comparing selected option to data attribute

Tags: jquery, compare

I've been strugling on a little code which I thought was simple, but somehow I can't find the bug (my error) in it.

I'm working on a website where one can filter on events. The filter is a form with drop down menu, and the events carry html data tags about what type of event they are. Any event of which the data tag equals to the selected option has class 'hide' removed, else it is added.

In the console log I get the selected option and the data tags nicely, however, ones I submit to filter all the events get the class 'hide'.

The HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>InfinityPlanner.net</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

<!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="headerBackground">
    <header class="grid-container">
        <img src="images/infinity2.png" alt="">
    </header>
</div>

<!-- FILTER -->
<div class="grid-container">
    <form id="filterForm">
        <div class="grid-20">
            <select class="type filter" name="type">
                <option value="ITS">ITS</option>
                <option value="Casual">Casual</option>
                <option value="Tournament">Tournament</option>
                <option value="Event">Event</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-20">
            <input type="submit" class="filter submit" id="submit" value="FILTER >>">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- EVENTS -->
<div class="fullScreenPane grid-container">
    <div class="grid-33">
        <div class="events" data-event="Casual">
            <h2>Thursday Night Infinity</h2>
            <h3>Casual</h3>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li>2015-02-26</li>
                <li>&euro; 0.00</li>
                <li>Gamers of the West</li>
                <li></li>

            </ul>
            <p><p>Elke donderdag avond gamen bij Gamers of the West. Van ITS scenario's tot YAMS!</p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-33">
        <div class="events" data-event="Tournament">
            <h2>Rotterdam Infinity Cup</h2>
            <h3>Tournament</h3>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li>2015-02-28</li>
                <li>&euro; 7.50</li>
                <li>Gamers of the West</li>
                <li>Rotterdam</li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/387748111350209/?ref_newsfeed_story_type=regular&amp;fref=nf" target="_blank">Website</a></li>

            </ul>
            <p><p>Who will be hunter and who will be prey? Come and join us and get the only Rotterdam Infinity Counter Pack part 1!</p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-33">
        <div class="events" data-event="ITS">
            <h2>N3 ITS 2015 Tafelridder</h2>
            <h3>ITS</h3>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li>2015-04-12</li>
                <li>&euro; 10.00</li>
                <li>De Tafelridder, Leiden</li>
                <li></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.tafelridder.nl" target="_blank">Website</a></li>

            </ul>
            <p><p>Come to our second Infinity Event at the Tafelridder.</p><p>For now we will work towards N3 ITS 2015 Rules at 300 points. May change later; final rulespack will be published a month before the event.</p><p>Hope people are excited; we are!</p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
    <h3>Powered by:</h3>
    <a href="http://www.gamersofthewest.com/"><img src="images/GOTW.jpg" alt="Gamers of the West"></a>
    <a href="http://www.data-sphere.net"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="DataSpehe"></a>
</footer>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// vars
var $form = $('#filterForm');

// On submit.
$form.submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $selected = $('select.type');
    filterEvents($selected);

});

// Filter events.
function filterEvents($selected){

        console.log($selected);

    // check data attribute for each event.
    $('.events').each(function($selected){

        var $this = $(this),
            $eventtype = $(this).data('event');

        console.log('eventtype = '+$eventtype);

        if ($eventtype == $selected){
            $this.removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $this.addClass('hide');
        }
    });
}
});
```

I'm probably doing somethng wrong, but I just don't see it.

Comment: `$selected` is a jQuery object not a value.

Comment: I figured that out :) Then I tried to use .val on it but that still didn't work.

Comment: Is that because you tried `.val` instead of `.val()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$selected.val()` to fetch the value of select.

```
if ($eventtype == $selected.find("option:selected").val()){
            $this.removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $this.addClass('hide');
        }
```

Comment: Sadly that replies with undefined is not a function. I used .val earlier on<br>

      <code>var $selected = $('select.type').val()<br>

But that gives the same problem of adding .hide to all the events

Comment: That still returns undefined. Thanks for helping btw, I was getting rather frustrated.